# My EF Core FromSqlRaw query returns strange data into a List in my data repository service. (in Blazor Server app)

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

Context:

- I have a Blazor server application
- I created a service to return some data from database to a List, registered it in Startup.cs as Transient
- the below is a method in that service
- parameter "acct" can contain a list of accounts (string) separated by comma (e.g. "1210,1171,2080" is a list of three accounts, 1210, 1171, 2080 )
- the stored procedure in the QueryString resulting below is perfectly fine, runs well inside SQL Server, using all possible parameters, including accounts with comma separated values
- the value of generated in mytrialbalance is totally strange, returns a list having a the same row repeated n times (n being the number of accounts in acct), for example, in this case, three lines, repeating the same info 3 times, according the query executed on the server, but copying the first resulting line of the executing query 3x

```
public async Task<List<TrialBalanceReport>> GetTBForAccountAsync(string acct, int per, string bu)
{
            try
            {
                if (acct.IndexOf(",") > 0)
                {
                    string QueryString = $"EXECUTE dbo.spTrialBalanceByAcctList {per}, '{bu}','{acct}'";
                    var mytrialBalance = new List<TrialBalanceReport>();                    
                    mytrialBalance = await _context.TrialBalanceReport.FromSqlRaw(QueryString).ToListAsync();
                    return mytrialBalance;
                }
                           
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return new List<TrialBalanceReport>();
            }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you have configured your `TrialBalanceReport` as entity with PK which actually is not unique. Either correct that or configure it as [keyless entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations) (a.k.a. query (result) type).

Comment: yes, the keyless entity type as mentioned above is the solution. just changed the fluent validation to         entity.HasNoKey(); in the context, modelbuilder. It works now, thank you very much!